# ruby on rails *_url returning wrong address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, rails-generate

I'm sending emails from rails, and using the *_url helper to generate urls.

However, these links are starting:

```
https://admin.test.website.co.uk/
```

(which is what the URL *used* to start with), whereas they should start:

```
https://production.test.website.co.uk/
```

Anyone know what could be going wrong..?

Comment: can you paste your routes here?

Comment: surely routes only controls paths (i.e. the bit at the end of the URL), not the base of the URL..?

Comment: well normally you pass resources to those helpers and it "figures" out how to build the url. AFAIK it has everything to do with, specially if you are are using "your_resourcename"_url

Answer (score 0):

What I think is going on is that you send the e-mails from your admin-interface. When using a generated _url helper, the host is generated from your current host, if present. If you want to override this, you can specify the host yourself using a variable or even hard-code it.

So, for example, instead of using `page_url`, you could use `page_url(:host => 'https://production.test.website.co.uk/')`

Good luck!